# node.js cheerio (scraping) live updating page

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

There is a webpage with live text data in a span tag that updates without the page refreshing. Is it possible to use cheerio or maybe another node.js module to get the page info and keep it open so node.js also sees the updates?

I would like to not keep re-requesting. As A human with the webpage open in the browser i do not need to refresh so logically the same should be doable in node.js

True?

Comment: Show us your code =)

Comment: I am trying to first understand what is the correct node.js tool before i start to write code. Besides the question is me asking whether something is achievable, no-where do I say there is a problem with code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)
It's like a real browser but without window.

You can handle all browser event, so you can know when an element is added to page.